# rename persistentstore coordinator URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

i have a (proably) simple to fix issue with my coredata persistent store.

i created it with:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"dummyURL.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }  

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

using the url `dummyURL.sqlite`

i did this on the first day working with the project, and have forgotten to rename it.. now all my current test devices (4) were in use for over 2 month, using the application, collecting a lot of data and storing it with a stupid url ^^

**UPDATE** i did some research on migration of persistent stores and wrote this function:

```
-(void)migrate{

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [self.dataHandler.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSURL *oldURL = [psc URLForPersistentStore:[[psc persistentStores]objectAtIndex:0]];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSURL *newURL = [[appDelegate applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSPersistentStore *oldStore = [psc persistentStoreForURL:oldURL];
    NSPersistentStore *newStore = [psc migratePersistentStore:sqliStoreOld
                                                           toURL:newURL
                                                         options:nil
                                                        withType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                        error:&error];

}
```

**QUESTION 1** `will this work or will i lose some data with that?`

**QUESTION 2** `afterwards will i just have to change the appendString in my persistenstore function?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i managed to solve it myself using the migratePersistentStore function:

```
-(void)migrate{

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [self.dataHandler.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSURL *oldURL = [psc URLForPersistentStore:[[psc persistentStores]objectAtIndex:0]];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSURL *newURL = [[appDelegate applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSPersistentStore *oldStore = [psc persistentStoreForURL:oldURL];
    NSPersistentStore *newStore = [psc migratePersistentStore:sqliStoreOld
                                                           toURL:newURL
                                                         options:nil
                                                        withType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                        error:&error];

}
```

afterwards i just changed the appendURL to `database.sqli` in my appDelegate.
works like a charm :)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend creating a second persistent store with the new URL and adding a button somewhere that copies all of the data you have into the new one. 
Make sure you test to make sure all your data is in the new persistent store before you remove the old one from the app.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. i am a bit shady on the persistentstore concept (thats why i didnt touch it anymore after creating it)... 
im currently exploring `migratePersistentStore` but im afraid to actually try it because of dataloss.. :/ 
where would i put a migration code?